# Max over heal number flickering?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

I noticed when I was playing medic once I was healing a Heavy and I over healed him. His max (with over heal) is 450, but I noticed that when I was over healing him the number kept flickering from 449 to 450. Why? is this a bug or what is the problem. I nor him was taking any damage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While constantly healing someone, the health of that person increases. However, if you over-heal them, the number will start to decrease until it goes back to the maximum life. You will always see the number fluctuate between the 150% over-heal and the number below that. What you are seeing here is normal, not a bug.

As @Toomai said in the comments below, this isn't seen in low-health classes such as scout because their over-heal decays slower.

Comment: Note that you don't see this on low-health classes because their overheal doesn't decay as fast as high-health ones.